# Error calling subprocess on python when redirecting stdout

Tags: python, subprocess

I tried to filter a file that was generated by a function in a python script:

```
out = subprocess.check_output(["sed","-n","'s/pattern/&/p'",oldFile,">",newFile])
```

However, I got the followong error about my command:

```
returned non-zero exit status 1
```

What is wrong?

Comment: Redirection operators are interpreted by the shell.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As devnull stated, the `>` is interpreted by the shell. Since it is [better to avoid using `shell=True`](http://docs.python.org/2/library/subprocess.html#frequently-used-arguments), use the `stdout` parameter instead:

```
import subprocess
with open(newFile, 'w') as newFile:
    subprocess.check_call(
        ["sed", "-n", "s/S/&/p", oldFile], stdout=newFile)
```

Comment: @Martijn and unutbu: I get: stdout argument not allowed, it will be overridden

Comment: With `check_output`, the stdout argument is not allowed as it is used internally. Use Popen instead.

Comment: Or use `call()` or `check_call()`.

Comment: Yes, maybe check_call would be closest.

Comment: I used call, check_call and Popen. Now, the error is AttributeError: 'str' object has no attribute 'fileno'. I guess it is because oldFile and newFile are fileNames given as strings. How can I correct this?

Comment: Notice in my post that `newFile` is not a string. Use the `with open(...) as newFile` statement.

Comment: I didn't see that in both your posts in fact. Thanks

Answer (score 2):

You are using `>` redirections, which require a shell to interpret the syntax.

When you are redirecting the output of `sed`, there is no point is using `check_output` here. Use [`subprocess.call()`](http://docs.python.org/2/library/subprocess.html#subprocess.call) or [`subprocess.check_call()`](http://docs.python.org/2/library/subprocess.html#subprocess.call) instead and verify the return code.

Either run the command through the shell:

```
import pipes

out = subprocess.call("sed -n 's/S/&/p' {} > {}".format(
    pipes.quote(oldFile), pipes.quote(newFile), shell=True)
```

or use a pipe:

```
with open(newFile, 'w') as pipetarget:
    out = subprocess.call(["sed", "-n", "s/S/&/p", oldFile],
                                  stdout=pipetarget)
```

Note that you shouldn't use quotes on the `'s/S/&/p'` string when used as a separate argument in the argument list; when not passing that to the shell it doesn't need escaping from shell parsing either.